# I have ray class and line class and want to find line-ray intersection point

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I wrote classes for Ray, Line, Point, and some other shapes, but I was stopped by the need for a function that takes a Line class object and a Ray class object as a parameter, and returns the point at which the line and the ray intersect.

Point class:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self.x

        elif index == 1:
            return self.y

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"x = {self.x}; y = {self.y}"
```

Ray class:

```
class Ray:
    def __init__(self, start: Point, end: Point):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        
    def get_direction(self):
        x_diff = self.end[0] - self.start[0]
        y_diff = self.end[1] - self.start[1]
        return (x_diff, y_diff)
```

Line class:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, point1: Point, point2: Point):
        self.point1 = point1
        self.point2 = point2

    def get_direction(self) -> tuple:
        x_diff = abs(self.point2[0] - self.point1[0])
        y_diff = abs(self.point2[1] - self.point1[1])
        return (x_diff, y_diff)
        
    def get_params(self) -> tuple:
        x1, y1 = self.point1
        x2, y2 = self.point2
        
        a = y2 - y1
        b = x1 - x2
        c = x2 * y1 - x1 * y2
        
        return a, b, c
    
    def get_normal(self):
        a, b, c = self.get_params()
        return -b, a, c
```

And perhaps the following functions can help:
Is the point on the line?

```
def point_on_line(point: Point, line: Line):
        x1, y1 = line.point1
        x2, y2 = line.point2
        x, y = point

        return (y - y1) * (x2 - x1) == (y2 - y1) * (x - x1)
```

Is the point on the ray?

```
def point_on_ray(point: Point, ray: Ray) -> bool:
    start = ray.start
    end = ray.end
    direction = ray.get_direction()

    x_diff = point[0] - start[0]
    y_diff = point[1] - start[1]

    if x_diff * direction[1] == y_diff * direction[0]:
        if x_diff >= 0 and y_diff >= 0:
            return True

    return False
```

I am bad in Math so i asked ChatGPT to help me, but he wrote some functions which will return wrong result

I tried giving ChatGPT several completely different prompts, and I got several completely different functions in response, but anyway, they all didn't work. Some of them returned the wrong points, some of them thought the ray and the line were parallel, although they have not worked correctly

Comment: think your point_on_ray() function returns True if the point is on the same direction of the Ray even with the point being outside of it (I got the ray is some sort of segment of a line)

Comment: It will be very difficult to egt this to work without understanding vectors.

Comment: @Beta so Ray is a vector ?? A Point has position in space. The only characteristic that distinguishes one point from another is its position. • A Vector has both magnitude and direction, but no fixed position in space.

Comment: @pippo1980: A point and a vector are equivalent. A ray -- in the mathematical sense -- is equivalent to a normalized vector. And my previous comment stands (apart from the typo).

Comment: Mmmh, difficult to folllow I'll try to google more. The OP incipit doesnt help : '  I wrote classes for Ray, Line, Point, and some other shapes, .... ' to me was like Ray was a shape too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve equation system

```
ray.start.x + t * ray.diff.x = line.point1.x + u * line.diff.x
ray.start.y + t * ray.diff.y = line.point1.y + u * line.diff.y
```

for unknowns `t` and `u`, then check that `t >= 0`

Then substitute `t` value into the left parts to get intersection point coordinates.

Standalone Python function

```
def ray_line_intersection(rx0, ry0, rdiffx, rdiffy, lx0, ly0, ldiffx, ldiffy):
    denom = ldiffy * rdiffx - ldiffx * rdiffy

    if denom == 0:    #ray and line are parallel or coincident
        return (1) if (lx0 - rx0) * rdiffy == (ly0 - ry0) * rdiffx else None

    t = (ldiffx * (ry0 - ly0) + ldiffy * (lx0 - rx0)) / denom
    return (rx0 + rdiffx * t, ry0 + rdiffy * t) if t >=0 else None

print(ray_line_intersection(0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, -1, 1))
print(ray_line_intersection(0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1))
print(ray_line_intersection(0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 4, 4))
print(ray_line_intersection(0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1))

>>> (1.5, 1.5) normal intersection
>>> None   parallel
>>> 1      ray lies  in the line 
>>> None  intersection beyond ray range
```

Comment: cant find diff in Ray objects

Comment: @pippo1980  `get_direction` in both author's classes